# executing ls command and printing output it

Tags: c++

so i have made this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  while(true)
  {
     string x;
     string y;
     string an1[3] = {"quit","exit","leave"};
     double ver = 0.1;
     cout << "basic0.1% ";
     cin >> x;
    if (x == "upgrade")
     {
      system("yay -Syyu");
     }
     else if (x == "install")
     {
      cout << "What do you want to install?" << "\n";
      cin >> y;
      system(("sudo yay -S " + y).c_str());
     }
     else if (x == "version")
     {
       cout << "version: " << ver << "\n"; 
     }
     else if (x == "clear")
     {
       system("clear");
     }

     else if(x == "quit" || "leave" || "exit")
     {
       break;
     }
     else if(x == "ls")
     {

     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and in the `else if(x == "ls"){}` i wanted to show the output of the command,i tried putting `system("ls");`
but it just exits the program.
btw this should be a little terminal emulator for linux but i am not sure yet,i am just having some fun.

Comment: Using `system()` is a very inelegant way of doing this. Look at `popen()` as an alternative, this will allow you to create a child that executes the command and provide a two communication stream to communicate with the child processes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`system("ls").` works fine. Your problem is this:

```
    else if(x == "quit" || "leave" || "exit")
    {
      break;
    }
```

Let's say you type `ls`. Then `x` contains the string "ls". `x == "quit"` is false because you didn't type `quit`. `"leave"` is true because it's a non-null pointer. `"exit"` is true because it's a non-null pointer. `false || true || true` is true, so the program quits.

Comment: FWIW, I recommend [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) instead of `system()` - faster, more focused, probably safer too.